# Segmentation Fault with strlen

Tags: c

I am getting a segmentation fault error. When I comment out "wordlength = strlen(token);" it runs fine. I don't know why it the seg fault happens when I assign a strlen(token) just fine to an int a few lines before this one. I would appreciate any help possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define char_max 60
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[2],"r");

    char **wordlist;
    int row = 1;
    int i;
    char temp[100];
    char *token;
    int wordlength;
    int lengthcounter;
    wordlist = (char**)malloc(row*sizeof(char*));
    for(i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
         wordlist[i] = (char*)malloc(char_max*sizeof(char*));
    }

    while(fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), fp) != NULL)
    {
        lengthcounter = 0;
        wordlength = 0;

        token = strtok(temp, " ");
        strcat(wordlist[row-1], token);
        printf("%s\n", wordlist[row-1]);
        lengthcounter = strlen(token);

        while(token != NULL)
        {
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            wordlength = strlen(token);
            /*lengthcounter += wordlength;*/ 
        }

        printf("The lengthcounter is %d\n", lengthcounter);

    }

    free(wordlist);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: seems like you arent checking if token could be null before you dereference it - try and confirm that with gdb

Comment: Worth noting that wordlength is an int, while strlen returns a size_t.

Comment: this line: 'wordlist[i] = (char*)malloc(char_max*sizeof(char*));' should be: 'wordlist[i] = malloc(char_max);' for several reasons: 1) in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc().  2) the code wants a pointer to an array of characters placed into wordlist[i].  but the line is making that allocation several times as long by multiplying by 'sizeof(char*)'  Note: a char* is (depending on the underlying system) either 4 or 8 bytes

Comment: when #define'ing a number, allways wrap the number in parens '(' and ')' to avoid possible character replacement problems.

Comment: compiler raises warning that 'argc' not used.  Given the posted code, there needs to be a check that 'argc' indicates the correct number of parameters (and if not that correct number, then printf a 'usage' message and exit

Comment: regarding this line: ' FILE *fp = fopen(argv[2],"r");'  always check (!=NULL) the returned value from fopen (and family of functions) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: there is the hardecoded magic number '100'  such hardcoded values should never be in the code,  Rather #define BUF_LEN (100)  then use BUF_LEN where the code currently contains 100.   For this simple code, it may not seem worthwhile, but as the code gets larger and the number of magic numbers grows, it becomes very important to properly name/define magic numbers in a single place,  especially when it comes time to maintain the code

Comment: the rows in char**wordList have not been initialized to all '\0', so the call to strcat() will start the concatenation where ever it actually finds a '\0' byte, which probably will not even be within the bounds to the row.  This results in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: the inner while loop steps through the input line 'temp', setting 'token' and 'wordlength' but does nothing with those values.

Comment: when freeing the malloc'd memory allocations, first each row needs to be free'd then the initial array of pointers needs to be free'd.  The current code does not free the allocated rows, resulting in a memory leak.

Comment: thanks for letting me know about having to free the rows first I would have completely forgotten to do that. Also argc is going to be used I'm just not there yet in my program. Thank you guys for all your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        wordlength = strlen(token);
        /*lengthcounter += wordlength;*/ 
    }
```

What happens in the last iteration of the loop when `token` *is* `NULL`? You pass it to `strlen` anyway.

Also, this is almost certainly wrong:

```
     wordlist[i] = (char*)malloc(char_max*sizeof(char*));
```

You're allocating space for pointers, not characters. So why `sizeof(char*)`? Also, don't cast the return value of `malloc`. This is C, not C++.

Comment: Thank you that exactly what it was. the sizeof(char*) was a mistake I am still new to C and pointer still confuse me.